# Unable to set Enviroment Variable when publishing dotnet core 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having problems with running my dotnet core 2.0 API (on Ubuntu 16.04 using  .NET Core CLI) using the correct Environment settings.

I added into the "~/.bash_profile" the following:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=staging
```

When i run the project (using dotnet run) it seems to work correctly, It detects that it should be on staging.
However, when i compile using "dotnet publish"
and try to run it using:

```
nohup dotnet API.dll --urls "http://*:1337" &> /var/log/dotnetlogs
```

it does not seem to detect the environment variable and always defaults to using the "Production" environment.

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

Any idea how i can get this working?

Comment: Make sure your environment variable isn't getting overwritten in `launchSettings.json`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However i believe that launchSettings.json is generated by Visual Studio, and the .NET Core CLI does not create this file when building/publishing. And in fact, i can not find this file anywhere on the ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the **export**? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) also say that Linux is case-sensitive, so you'll probably want to use **Staging**.

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
```

Comment: Hi, and thx. The export is not missing (i only excluded it here). Regarding the case-sensitivity, i tested with "Staging" instead of "staging" but no avail. Also it defaults to "Production", not "staging", and works fine when i am not publishing the project.